# Side by side components in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an icon and text in a container side by side by using a row and a column but I haven't been able to get results I want. On the first picture[image] it's my code and on the second[image] it's what I want to achieve. Any help would be app. Also, how do I implement a divider with a different color? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TextField` in your `ReusableCard` right?
Sure thing you can make it with `Row` but in this case this is usually done with `suffixIcon` property:

```dart
TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
```

Or you can just wrap children widgets that has to be in a row in a, well `Row` widget. Here is example:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  TextStyle _style = TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[800], fontSize: 30);
  Color _color = Colors.yellow[800];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Material App Bar'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.done, color: _color),
                  SizedBox(width: 15),
                  Text('Electricity', style: _style),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.done, color: _color),
                  SizedBox(width: 15)
                ],
              ),
              Divider(color: _color),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.done, color: _color),
                  SizedBox(width: 15),
                  Text('Internet', style: _style),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.done, color: _color),
                  SizedBox(width: 15)
                ],
              ),
              Divider(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I am actually using a text and an icon. here's my code:
`  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          icon,
          size: 80,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Text(
          label,
          style: labelTextStyle,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }`

Comment: @Reagan, updated answer, I do not know exact code of your widget tree, so this is just a sample.

Comment: I used your technique and it worked, I just changed the `mainAxisAlignment` to start.

Answer (score 0):

Spacing / alignment of the icons will be tricky without using `Stack`, but it could be done with lots of fiddling around with padding/margin.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


final bool debug = false;

class RowColLayoutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Row Col Layout'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: debug ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : null,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: RowIcon(icon: Icons.lightbulb)
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: RowText(text: 'Electricity')
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RowDivider(),
          Container(
            color: debug ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : null,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: RowIcon(icon: Icons.microwave_rounded,)
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: RowText(text: 'Internet')
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RowDivider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;

  RowIcon({this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: debug ? Border.all() : null
        ),
        child: Icon(icon, size: 80,)
    );
  }
}

class RowText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  RowText({this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: debug ? Border.all() : null
        ),
        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40))
    );
  }
}

class RowDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.blue, indent: 15, endIndent: 15,);
  }
}
```

[image]